# How do I get OpenCL C++ bindings on Mac OSX 10.9.4 for Intel Iris Pro

Tags: c++, macos, opencl

I want to utilize the Intel Iris Pro with OpenCL, preferably 1.2, on a mac (10.9.4) with C++ bindings.

I am extremely new to Mac and I have struggled a bit with XCode in getting a simple OpenCL code compiled even after going through Apple's OpenCL documentation. I think I would be much more comfortable with the command line as opposed to GUI solutions.

So how do I go about getting C++ API of OpenCL 1.2 working for Iris Pro? Would Intel OpenCL SDK work on OSX? Is there any way to just add to the libraries already provided on Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official C++ bindings from Khronos are header-only. You can get cl.hpp at [Khronos OpenCL registry](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/). BTW, look at your OpenCL SDK, usually it's available out of the box. If not, include mentioned C++ header, and that's it.

Comment: I copied cl.hpp to /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/
Compiling it with "g++ -o exec prog.cpp -framework OpenCL" does not work but it works with "clang++ -o exec prog.cpp -framework OpenCL". Is there any reason why this happens? What am I losing by not being able to use g++?

Anyway, I will be using clang++ to do OpenCL coding on OSX for now. Thanks.

Comment: g++ takes flags in another format. It should look like follows: g++ -o app app.cpp -lOpenCL